# Request Sign Off , how to wait for all responses by default

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, ms-flow

I am working on an online SharePoint communication site, and by default we can use the Request sign-off feature on our document library:-

[image]

but let say i add two users to the Approver field:-

[image]

then when the first user respond to the sing-off request the status will be reflected and the second request will be invalid. so can i modify this behavior so the Request Sign-off will wait for all the responses?. My question is whether i can force this behavior to be the default behavior without the need to modify the MS Flow itself, as we have non-technical people how are using this feature ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design if you add more than one approver, any one of them can approve your request.

This Flow is a built-in Flow and we have no choice to change it.

We suggest you create a customized request Flow.